# Unable to refresh/update browsefragment using ArrayObjectAdaptor's clear() and addAll()

Tags: android-tv, leanback, browsefragment

I have a browsefragment thats displaying rows from a JSON file generated by PHP when a PHP page is called. I am trying to get the browsefragment to refresh the rows as the JSON data will be changing regularly.

Following the instructions on https://hackernoon.com/how-to-refresh-the-android-tv-browsefragment-6e4d2d3c6690, I added clear() and addAll() methods found in the ArrayOjectAdapter.

The main portion of my browseFragment is:

```
public class MainFragment extends BrowseSupportFragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<LinkedHashMap<String, List<Video>>>{

    private static final int BACKGROUND_UPDATE_DELAY = 300;

    private static final String TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    static final int GRID_ITEM_WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int GRID_ITEM_HEIGHT = 200;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter;
    private Drawable mDefaultBackground;
    private DisplayMetrics mMetrics;
    private Runnable mBackgroundTask;
    private Uri mBackgroundURI;
    private BackgroundManager mBackgroundManager;
    private CustomListRow mGridItemListRow;
    private LoaderManager mLoaderManager;
    private static final int CATEGORY_LOADER = 123; 

    ArrayList<Video> mItems = null;
    private ArrayList<CustomListRow> mVideoListRowArray;
    private static final int VIDEO_ITEM_LOADER_ID = 1;


    private static PicassoBackgroundManager picassoBackgroundManager = null;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        prepareBackgroundManager();

        setupUIElements();

        loadRows();
        setRows();

        mLoaderManager = LoaderManager.getInstance(this);
        mLoaderManager.initLoader(VIDEO_ITEM_LOADER_ID, null, this);

        setupEventListeners();
        prepareEntranceTransition();


        picassoBackgroundManager = new PicassoBackgroundManager(getActivity());
        picassoBackgroundManager.updateBackgroundWithDelay("http://twende.phidampalmgardens.com/images/bkground/background1.jpg");

        updateRecommendations();


        if(mVideoListRowArray != null) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //mLoaderManager.restartLoader(CATEGORY_LOADER, null, MainFragment.this);

                    mRowsAdapter.clear();
                    mRowsAdapter.addAll(0, mVideoListRowArray);
                }
            }, 2000);

        }

    }
```

Unfortunately, I still cannot get the rows to refresh/update without having to close and reopen the app

Comment: Where is the code where you refresh the data and react to it? Based on the provided code it seems like you only do so in `onActivityCreated`, which would explain why you have to reopen the app to see the changes in data.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `mRowsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` statement:

```
mRowsAdapter.clear();
mRowsAdapter.addAll(0, mVideoListRowArray);
mRowsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Hi @burakk, Thanks for the response. Unfortunately notifyDataSetChanged() is in the ArrayAdaptor class not ArrayObjectAdaptor so cant use it

Comment: Are you sure that the mVideoListRowArray is updated correctly?

Comment: Please post some more code including loadRows, setRows methods, and your custom object adapter.

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` is unnecessary, `addAll` already calls `notifyItemRangeInserted`.

Comment: @BenjaminBreiby Yes, correct. I thought that it could be missing in the implementation of the custom adapter. Now I see that mRowsAdapter is of type ArrayObjectAdapter, so the custom adapter is not being used at all...?